# Processing Deltas

Tags: python, node.js, postgresql

We are building a **middleware** {built using Node Js and postgresql} that will get data from Company A in a **txt file**, process/transform that data, and deliver it to Company B in form of a CSV file.

The issue is Company B only accepts **incremental data** (data that is new/changed) but Company A will send the full load.

We are thinking to create a **hash-key** for each record in a file and compare that whenever a new load is sent. The only issue is that there will be millions of records and will require a lot of space to store historical data.

Is there a smart way to tackle this type of use case, thanks? Maybe a python script or something.

Comment: I'm guessing the delta isn't just new records for insert but also change records? Would it also contain deletes (records that were present yesterday, but not today)? How will the target system process these deltas? Can you just send the full load directly to them and have them perform an UPSERT/MERGE operation, essentially treating the full load as a delta (again that will be dependent on there being a unique key).